# Detecting patterns ("stripes","squares",...) in clustered heatmaps

Tags: matrix, data-analysis

Currently I am facing a problem in my data analysis:

I have a number of matrices where I want to "identify"/"detect" squares and/ or stripes in my matrices where the values of the cells are *consistently low*  (I could accept both to set a threshold (i.e. everything below 0.5 is a cell which is part of the "squares" I want to detect) or a parametric approach (everything below the 10th percentile of the distribution of values)).

Does anybody have an idea about how to approach the following part i.e. make the script understand and tell me if this parts with lower values are squares or "stripes".

Thank you all

Answer (score 0):

Depending on how large your matrices are and the range of values you can either explore ML image recognition libraries or DIY a simple algorithm:

For example:

1. Determine the threshold, either fixed or calculated by looking at percentiles
2. Apply the threshold to the matrix, i.e. everything below the threshold is 0, above 1
3. Find all occurrences of 0 in the matrix, and process neighboring elements to find clusters of 0.
4. Analyze the shape of the clusters to see which clusters are squares, lines or whatever. You could do this with exhaustive search, or draw a square between most top-left and bottom-right points, and count how many elements of the cluster are inside/outside the square. Apply a threshold as needed.